# Where is the function that displays the PDFs in the search function?

Tags: php, joomla, rokajaxsearch

I researched extensively and I couldn't find the solution to my problem.

The site I am working on is using Joomla 1.5 and the latest version of PDF Indexer + Rokajaxsearch.

Everything works great but I am having serious problems trying to **change the order the results are displayed**. By default it shows the PDF results first and then the page results, but **I would like it to show the page results first and then the PDF results.**  In order to do this, I need to rewrite the search function to switch the ordering.

I have been trying to find where the code for the search function, but I cannot figure out where it is. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: could you provide the code being used to currently display the results?

Comment: @Lodder I have tried to pin point the exact script that produced the output for the last 3 h but in all honesty.... I have no clue where that is. That's why I've posted this... if you know which file could have this info I am happy to supply it.